# How can I get clean this fields?

Tags: bash

**I have the following dateformat in a datatable:**

{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-06-07T15:34:52.796215","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"5", temperature 39, state_of_charge 70"}

{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-06-07T15:34:57.809638","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"5", temperature 39, state_of_charge 70"}

**I wrote this:**

`cut -d',' -f1,3,4 inputfile.csv | sed 's/{"__TIMESTAMP":"//g' | tr 'T' ' ' | tr '__DIAGNOSE_SLOT' ' ' | tr 'temperature' ' ' > outputfile.csv`

**I got this:**

> 2020-06-07 15:34:52.796215","               ":"5",             39
>
> 2020-06-07 15:34:57.809638","               ":"5",             39

**But I need this:**

2020-06-07 15:34:52,5,39

2020-06-07 15:34:57,5,39

**Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, using the `cut` from your question and then just `sed`:

`cut -d"," -f1,3,4 inputfile.csv | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^{__TIMESTAMP://' -e 's/__DIAGNOSE_SLOT://' -e 's/temperature//' -e 's/ \+//g' -e 's/T/ /' -e 's/\.[[:digit:]]\+//'`

```
2020-06-07 15:34:52,5,39
2020-06-07 15:34:57,5,39
```

To go through it a bit:

`'s/"//g'` to remove double quotes.

There's then 3 `sed` expressions to remove the text (timestamp, diagnose slot and temperature).

`'s/ \+//g'` removes spaces

`'s/T/ /'` to replace the `T` with a space.

`'s/\.[[:digit:]]\+//'` to remove numbers after a `.` (the decimal values)

Answer (score 1):

With bash, a regex and four back-references:

```
regex='^.*([0-9-]{10})T([0-9:]{8}).*__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"([0-9]+)".*temperature ([0-9]+).*$'

while read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]},${BASH_REMATCH[3]},${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
2020-06-07 15:34:52,5,39
2020-06-07 15:34:57,5,39
```